# Wordpress login issue . Permission Problem

Tags: login

I can't access wordpress admin panel after installation few plugins .
it's show **You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.**

I follow many instruction but did't help my problem .

1. I am checking database prefix and usermeta table all is good.
2. Rename Plugins and themes folder .
   But this is not help me 
   then define wp-config user and usermeta table also truncate user and usermeta table and import from new working db( changeing prefix when import ) 
   But nothing help me . 
   [image] 
   This is my user data what i get from when print current user information .
   Please help me out.
   ![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the database, try this:

Set `db_version` in the `wp_options` table to `8204`. Log out and then back into wp-admin. Click the upgrade database button, this should restore all admin privileges.

Comment: So you disabled all your plugins, and it's still not working? Can you provide a full screenshot of the whole page? Also, did you enable debug in the config?

Comment: Yes debug in enabled .Front end working fine .Problem in only admin panel.

Comment: ... screenshot?

Comment: http://joannebrocas.com/ check this link . Do you need db screen short ?

Comment: Unless you plan to give me admin access, this doesn't really help. I was asking for a screenshot of what the error shows. You sure you deactivated ALL the plugins?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1tPPtNQ.png

Comment: I updated my answer, try that

Comment: Follow you update answer but did't help . But i found a clue when i remove wp_option table and insert it from another site wp_option it's working fine .Please can you help me how to find out where is the problem in wp_option table .

Comment: What happened after you updated the table? Nothing?

Comment: Yes . again permission problem